# NullPointer with afterburner.fx when trying to create View

Tags: java, javafx

Afterburner.fx has broken for me and I can't seem to get it working again.

In my main method I have this:

```
 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Map<Object, Object> customProperties = new HashMap<>();
    Injector.setConfigurationSource(customProperties::get);

    final StackPane views = new StackPane();
    customProperties.put("views", views);

    BattleView battleView = new BattleView();
    Parent view = battleView.getView();
    view.setVisible( false );
    view.setId("battle");
    views.getChildren().add(view);

    ...
}
```

Yet I seem to hit an exception when I get to the `BattleView battleView = new BattleView();` line. Afterburner fx seems to be trying to evaluate `toString()` on `ui.battle.BattleView` and it doesn't like it, see the below picture:

[image]

And in the terminal results in:

[image]

I haven't found any help from similiar questions so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction! Help!

Edit: Same error after moving battle.css and battle.fxml to resources/ui/battle:

[image]

Edit2: [image]

Comment: Move your resource files (fxml and css) to `src/main/resources/ui/battle` and try again.

Comment: @JoséPereda, I have the same error. Editted in OP the picture so you can see. Thanks for the suggestion also! I was under the impression AfterburnerFX required by convention for them to be next to each other.

Comment: You are doing exactly that as you are using the same package name, but for Maven/Gradle projects you have to separate source classes from resources. As for the error, note that it complains about `Battle.fxml`, not `battle.fxml`, which is weird as it should look for an all lower case name. What is your afterburner version? Can you rename it to `Battle.fxml` and try again?

Comment: Same error with the rename.
Thanks for the Maven/Gradle info, I didn't know that. (updating this old project which didn't use modules/any build tool/Java11/JavaFX11, which I am all new to)
I'm using 1.7.0.

Comment: Did you check the whole stacktrace? Usually the error is at the end, and it happens because something is failing when loading the FXML.

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to see anything wrong. It's probably something obvious I'm missing as I'm not too familiar with the technology... would it be possible for you to have a look at the project if I sent it to you? I know it's asking above and beyond, I've just been stuck at this point for a few days now.

Comment: It would be easier if you can create a simple JavaFX project, add the Afterburner framework and see if that works for you. If it still doesn't work, you can edit your question and post the required files so we can test. If it does, see what's different in your project and try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Java 11 and module system, your resource output directory have to be in the same output directory as the module they belong to.

Judging by the images in your post, you're using gradle and you build your project directly from IDEA.

You need to tell IDE to copy your resources to the same output directory:

```
//build.gradle

plugins {
  ...
  id 'idea' //add idea plugin
}

...
//put compiled classes and resources in the same directory (change the path if needed)
idea.module.outputDir file("out/production/classes")
```

If you plan to build with gradle too:

```
//put compiled classes and resources in the same directory (change the paths if needed)
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/java/main"
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/java/test"
```

and you'll probably need to open package with resource files, so that the framework can access them:

```
//module-info.java
module YourModuleName {
    ...
    opens ui.battle to afterburner.fx; //add this
}
```

edit:

> The 'idea' in 'idea.module.outputDir' is greyed out with the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'idea''.

It's not really an error, but you can get rid of it easily:

```
//use this format instead of the previous one
idea {
    module.outputDir file("out/production/classes")
}
```

> Im getting an nullPointer error from input streams where I am trying to load resources, such as: setImage(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/ui/mineStartButton.png")));

Do not call `getClassLoader()` or you'll need to open the package with the image resource - even if the calling code is in the same module (check [Javadoc](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))):

```
//you need to add '/' at the beginning of the path string to make it absolute
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/ui/mineStartButton.png")
```

Comment: The 'idea' in 'idea.module.outputDir' is greyed out with the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'idea''. Although afterburner seems to be able to read everything now, apart from.. Im getting an nullPointer error from input streams where I am trying to load resources, such as:

setImage(newImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/ui/mineStartButton.png")));

In the screenshots in OP you can see the original resources folder that the above URL pointed to just fine, why doesn't it work anymore? tried to copy that entire folder to the new resources folder but still nothing...

Comment: I've editted in a picture of the error. I think this is the last thing to solve! There is light at the end of the tunnel (I think!) thanks for everything so far :)

Comment: Holy bat balls you've only gone and done it. Been struggling with all this for about a week and now everythings working properly, loading up and I've also learnt a tonne of stuff. Thanks a lot buddy, you really came through and I'll do my best to pass it on one day :)